# Module with no attribute python

Tags: python

I have importet the following modules.

```
import saxo_openapi
from saxo_openapi import API
import saxo_openapi.endpoints.referencedata as rd
```

with the class being
 `class saxo_openapi.endpoints.referencedata.exchanges.ExchangeList(params=None)`

so in my code write the following:

```
r = rd.exchanges.ExhangeList()
rv = client.request(r)
print(json.dumps(rv.response, indent=4))
```

i have also tried various other ways of writing it, like:

```
client = saxo_openapi.API(access_token=...)
r = rd.ExchangeList()
client.request(r)
print(json.dumps(r.response, indent=4))
```

but i get the same error all the time. I cant figure out, what i am missing.

> module 'saxo_openapi.endpoints.referencedata.exchanges' has no
>   attribute 'ExhangeList'

I really do hope you guys can help.

Comment: "ExhangeList"?  Shouldn't that be "Exchange"?

Comment: @FiddleStix from the class info. Not as i can see. I tried still get same error just "no attribute 'Exhange' "

Comment: There is a spelling error. remember the `c` in exchange. I had no problem with your code after that. `r = rd.exchanges.ExchangeList()`

Comment: oh.. jezz im so sorry! that made it thanks @pastaleg